# MAGENTO - How to display the category details for editing?

Tags: magento, categories

See the Image for reference [Categories Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr0RU.png)

I want to update categories in Magento but the problem is when I click to  sub-category (Desktop) the details of that category doesn't show up in the "General Infomation" form.

Also, the number of products in other categories displays zero (0) but there's data stored when you collapsed one of the category.

[Collapsed Category Child Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52b18.png)

---

In **System > Index Management**: I didn't do "Reindex Data" action

In **System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend (section)**: 
My **Use Flat Catalog Category**,**Use Flat Catalog Product** is set to `No`

Should I reindex data and set both flat catalog to `yes`? To solve my problem?

---

P.S The front-end is working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Click on category whose count shows zero then Go to Display Settings and change Is Anchor as "Yes" it will show all assigned products.

Comment: When I click on a category then click "Save Category" It says that I need to fill a required field because when I click on a category it doesn't give the details of that category in the "General Information" form (right pane) where you can modify the details.

Comment: check log why it is not showing category detail; there may be some error.